# EXCEL LOOK UP FORUMLA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, xlookup

I've two separate excel files, one containing a list of users which are assigned to a specific team, on the other excel I would like to search the first file to validate if the "user id" is contained on the list of users on "user list" excel and if yes then to tell me which user team they are in.

I've tried

```
=XLOOKUP([@[USER LIST]],'DATA Sheet'!A5:A128,'DATA Sheet'!B5:B128,[@[USER LIST]])
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a simple vlookup to be honest or an index / match. But I can't follow your links to see your data. It is better to include these things as text in your post so that we can cut / paste the information to reproduce the problem or test any solution offered

Answer (score 1):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX('DATA Sheet'!$A$1:$C$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN('DATA Sheet'!$A$2:$C$128)/('DATA Sheet'!$A$2:$C$128=A2),1))
```

Comment: This works thank you, but how can I tell the formula to ignore the blank fields, right now if I have any blanks in my array the "team" cell will still populate an incorrect value

Answer (score 0):

With SUM and INDEX

```
=INDEX('DATA Sheet'!$A$1:$C$1,,--SUM((A2='DATA Sheet'!$A$2:$C$128)*{1\2\3}))
```